# mysql --version still shows /usr/local/mysql/bin/mysql after brew install mysql

Tags: mysql, macos, homebrew

I installed MySQL on my Mac from DMG file long time ago and decide to install a new one using homebrew, everything seems to be fine, `which mysql` shows `/usr/local/bin/mysql`, which means I'm using the one installed by homebrew.

The wierd thing is  `mysql --version` shows `/usr/local/mysql/bin/mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.5.29, for osx10.6 (i386) using readline 5.1`. I have to type `/usr/local/bin/mysql --version` to get the right result, which is `/usr/local/bin/mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.6.13, for osx10.8 (x86_64) using  EditLine wrapper`.

So what is wrong? Does this matter?

Answer (score 0):

You can create `alias`

```
alias mysql=/usr/local/bin/mysql
```

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like your PATH may be out of order...

Make sure you have `/usr/local/bin` before `/usr/local/mysql/bin`.

Comment: seems not. `/usr/local/bin` is the first one on the PATH.